# How to numerically compute null space of a large-scale matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a large sparse matrix $A$ which is column rank-defficient. Typical size of $A$ is over 100000x100000. In my computation, I need the matrix $W$ whose columns span the null space of $A$. But I do not know how to fastly compute all the columns of W.

If $A$ is small-scale, I know there are several numerical methods based on matrix factorization, such as LU, QR, SVD. But for large-scale matrices, I can not find an efficient iterative method to do this.

Could you please give me some help?

Comment: Randomized methods are designed for problems of this scale. There are randomized algorithms for many classical matrix decompositions. This is a recent paper on computing an approximate null space with such methods https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.00975